# How to Cache Sharepoint Managed Client Object Model based objects?

Tags: sharepoint, caching, object, model, client

I need to Cache certain objects which are based on SharePoint Managed Client Object Model like ClientContext, GroupCollection, User , List etc. Initially I tried using Appfabric cache but it gives some issues like "cannot be serialized" . Here my question is "**Is it possible to serialize SharePoint Managed Client Object Model based Objects?**" .

Next I tried with .NET **ObjectCache** which actually caches the SP's Managed Client Objects but problem over here is I need a distributed / unified caching technique. As per my knowledge we cant make ObjectCache distributed over multiple hosting servers. Can anyone suggest me a solution or show me light to proceed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint Client Object Model will not support Object Cache w.r.t the Client objects. That is the limitation in Client Object Model.

Comment: Actually using ObjectCache i tried caching ClientContext and It worked fine for me. But my problem is I need it in Distributed Cache like AppFabric

Comment: @user1597990, could you share your experience about caching the ClientContext on local machine? We are looking for similar solution: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/c39e2fed-0530-4b07-9ae0-9c22704dfca1/should-we-cache-the-sharepoint-clientcontext-object?forum=appsforsharepoint

Answer (score 0):

You cannot serialize the context or the result of a query. Also a `ListItem` cannot be serialized. Nonetheless: At least when thinking about query-results the most important information you usually want to know is the content of the fields returned. 
So, `ListItem.FieldValues` is a simple `Dictionary<string,object>` which can be easily serialized.

You could use this Dictionary in combination with the Listitem's ID to create your own caching mechanism.